# Load fixture using Symfony and Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm creating web application using Symfony, also I use docker in my project. I want to load fixture `php bin/console doctrine:fixture:load`, but I get this error

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "my_els_db_postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

File `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
    services:
      database:
        container_name: my_els_db_postgres
        image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app_my_ELS}
          # You should definitely change the password in production
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}
          POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

.env:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@my_els_db_postgres:5432/app_my_ELS?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the port number?

Comment: I tried, still the same problem.

Comment: Does your symfony application run on a service defined in the same docker-compose.yml as the postgres ?

Comment: I've created new symfony project then I added service inside docker-compose.yml.
I run the app using symfony server:start

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki what is your operating system? Depending on it the solution maybe different.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you are using postgres from docker-compose but symfony/php from local installation? If that is the case there is no way for your local php to know that `my_els_db_postgres` hostname is docker container.
You can test if with `ping my_els_db_postgres`.
To solve this you will want to add postgres container IP address to your hosts file (and probably set static IP for it).

Otherwise if your php is also running from container please update the question with it's docker-compose configuration.

Comment: php is installed in my computer not in a container

Comment: As said @Aurelijus Rozenas, you run php in your computer, so you have to expose port 5432 throught `docker-compose` file or `dockerfile` and you can try this command to set correct ip address of pgsql container in `.env` file, `docker inspect app_simonagency-phpapache-1 | grep IPAddress (e.g 172.18.0.3)` so `.env` would be `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@172.18.0.3:5432/app_my_ELS?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"`. Also, set static ip for your container to avoid change everytime `.env` configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Use service name instead of container name.

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@database:5432/app_my_ELS?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"

Comment: same problem :   An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "database" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Is port exposed? Can you connect to database using GUI app like DBeaver?

Comment: Is PHP app running inside container too?

Comment: no php is installed only in my computer